# HashLink package throws odd type error? Is there another way to link to a particular part of the page?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Should be very simple. Here's the link to the package in question. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link.  I `npm install --save react-router-hash-link`, and then I `npm install --save @types/react-router-hash-link`. I made a new test file here:

```
import { HashLink } from "react-router-hash-link";

export default function testRoute(): JSX.Element { 
    return <HashLink to={"/assets"}>Assets</HashLink>
}
```

This throws the type error:

```
Type '{ children: string; to: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HashLinkProps & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HashLinkProps & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>'.ts(2322)
```

I personally can't figure out the types, the fact that it isn't expecting any children makes me think something is seriously wrong with my setup. I'm using npm 8.5.3.

If there is an easier way to link to a particular hash fragment please let me know.

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` do you have installed? From your project's directory run `npm list react-router-dom` and report back. Barring any obvious mistakes/issues think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: react-router-dom@5.3.0
react-router-hash-link@2.4.3
react-router-dom@5.3.0 deduped

Comment: codesandbox doesn't reproduce the issue, it works perfectly fine in the browser. Perhaps I should just uninstall and reinstall npm and run a fresh npm install on the directory?

Comment: Worth a try. If we can't reproduce the issue then we can't really help diagnose/debug it, right? Did you ensure matching versions in the codesandbox?